# How can I rearrange the exact sag equation?

Tags: trigonometry

I apologize if this is a basic question on a site such as this but my maths skills aren't the best.

The exact sag equation is $s = r - \sqrt{(r^2 - y^2)}$ we are required to know in my module that the rearrangement to find $r$ is $r = \frac{(y^2 + s^2)}{2s}$ but I am struggling to rearrange the equation to find this.
I asked my professor who told me it was fine to just memorize the equation and not understand how we got there but I would like to understand how we rearranged to find this, both to improve my mathematics and because I can bet I will need to know how we got here for the exam.

I searched online and watched many videos on rearrangements and expanding brackets but struggled to find one similar to this. I found a website where somebody goes through how they rearranged it the link is below.
https://www.optiboard.com/forums/showthread.php/15689-Rearranging-the-Sag-formula

They use this as a starting point $r^2 = y^2 + (r - s)^2$ which I understand but then the next step jumps to here $r^2 = y^2 + r^2 - 2rs + s^2$ the step was called after expanding but I am not sure how to expand to get here. I looked at an online calculator that said I should use the perfect square formula and upon researching what this is I became even more confused.

Please help!

Thank you for taking the time to read my question and I will appreciate any response I get! Sorry for the poor formatting I have never used this site and struggled to use the codes to make the squared and square root symbol. Thank you again!

Comment: $(r - s)^2 = (r - s) (r - s)=r(r - s)-s(r - s)= (r^2-rs)-(rs-s^2)=  r^2-2rs+s^2$

Answer (score 1):

$$s = r - \sqrt{r^2 - y^2}$$ can be rearranged to
$$\sqrt{r^2 - y^2} = r - s$$ and squaring both sides (possibly introducing a spurious root)
$${r^2 - y^2} = r ^2 -2rs +s^2$$ and simplifying
$$2rs = y^2+s^2$$ and thus $$r = \frac{y^2+s^2}{2s}$$
and you can check this works correctly by substitution

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand most of steps but I don't understand step 2. Where does the 2rs come from. If you square both sides we get r^2 - y^2 = r^2 - s^2 right? where do we get the 2rs we don't times by 2? Also in the equation the r^2 and y^2 have brackets around them which I forgot to add but will add now will that make a difference to the steps? Thank you again!

Comment: @James $(r - s)^2 = (r - s) (r - s)=r(r - s)-s(r - s)= (r^2-rs)-(rs-s^2)=  r^2-2rs+s^2$

Answer (score 0):

$$s=r-\sqrt{r^2-y^2}\\
\sqrt{r^2-y^2}=s-r\\
r^2-y^2=s^2-2sr+r^2\\
2sr=s^2+y^2\\
r=\frac{s^2+y^2}{2s}$$
As we squared in the third line we may have introduced an extraneous solution, so the solution needs to be checked back into the original equation

Comment: @Henry:  Thanks.  Fixed

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand most of steps but I don't understand step 2. Where does the 2rs come from. If you square both sides we get r^2 - y^2 = r^2 - s^2 right? where do we get the 2rs we don't times by 2? Also in the equation the r^2 and y^2 have brackets around them which I forgot to add but will add now will that make a difference to the steps? Thank you again!

Comment: No, squaring $(s-r)$ gives $s^2-2sr+r^2$.  That is a basic fact that you can prove by distributing the product $(s-r)(s-r)$